# Commutator of derivatives with torsion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

I am currently looking at "Physical aspect of space-time torsion" by IL Shapiro. There in eq. 2.10, it mentions that in space-time with torsion the commutator of covariant derivatives acting on the scalar $\phi$ gives $$[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu]\phi = K^\lambda_{~~~\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda \phi$$
Where $K$ is the contorsion tensor. Clearly this is incorrect. Shouldnt we instead have
$$[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu]\phi = T^\lambda_{~~~\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda \phi$$
Where $T$ is torsion? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You should specify the equation no. or page no. etc. while citing a specific equation from a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torsion is always defined by
$$
T(X,Y)= \nabla_X Y-\nabla_y X -[X,Y]
$$
and the curvature is defined by the commutator on a vector field as
$$
[\nabla_X,\nabla_Y] Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z=R(X,Y)Z.
$$
This last equation holds both  with and without torsion in the connection.

On a scalar the commutator is given by
$$
[\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]\phi - \nabla_{[X,Y]}\phi= 0
$$
as  the scalar does not see curvature. So, using the coordinate basis vectors $X=\partial_\mu$, $Y=\partial_\nu$, we have
$$
[\nabla_{\partial_\mu},\nabla_{\partial_\nu}]\phi=0.
$$

It's not safe  to write $\nabla_{\partial_\mu}$ as $\nabla_\mu$ as this gives the impression that you need an extra connection term because of the $\nu$ index when $\nabla_\mu$ acts on $\nabla_\nu$ etc. If you make this interpretation then then the $\nabla_\mu$ changes the tensor character of the object it acts on, unlike the usual covariant derivative $\nabla_X$ which does not change the tensor character.  If you insist of changing the character then $\nabla_\mu$ and $\nabla_\nu$ are acting on different spaces depending on their order, and the "commutator" is not really a commutator and its properties are rather ill defined.  This is harmless in torsion-free GR but becomes a probelm when you have torsion as it leads to  notational ambguities that I suspect  you have in your paper.

The torsion definition applied to $X=\partial_\mu$, $Y=\partial_\nu$ gives
$$
\nabla_{\partial_\mu} \partial_\nu - \nabla_{\partial_\nu}\partial_\mu = T^{\lambda}(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu)  \partial_\lambda.
$$
With
$$
T^\lambda(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu)= {T^\lambda}_{\mu\nu}
$$
as the coordinate componets of the torsion tensor, and
applying the vector field ${T^\lambda}_{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda$  to a scalar $\phi$ we get
$$
(\nabla_{\partial_\mu} \partial_\nu - \nabla_{\partial_\nu}\partial_\mu) \phi = {T^{\lambda}}_{\mu\nu}  \partial_\lambda \phi.
$$
which suggests that you opinion that  $K$ should be replaced by $T$  is correct.

Also, by the definition of the Christoffel symbols
$$
\nabla_{\partial_\mu} \partial_\nu= {\Gamma^\lambda}_{\nu\mu} \partial_\lambda
$$
we see that the above dequation  gives the usual
$$
{T^{\lambda}}_{\mu\nu}= {\Gamma^\lambda}_{\nu\mu}-{\Gamma^\lambda}_{\mu\nu}
$$ where I am using MTW's placement of the indices on the $\Gamma$'s, so the indices might seem to be backwards compared to  some other defs.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you can put the entire derivation of the equation. I would be most grateful.

Comment: The formulae for the torsion and the curvature are the usual *definitions* in differential geometry, so there is no real "derivation." There is a good discussion in Misner, Thorn and Wheeler, although I suspect that they do not consider torsion. I  learnt them from books on differential geometry.  Lots of people use $\nabla_\mu$ and have extra torsion terms in their "commutators" and you *can* be consistent if you are careful.  It's just always safer to use $\nabla_X = X^\mu\nabla_\mu$ fo these things.

Comment: I've added some extra material to my answer.

Comment: I am glad that somebody agrees with me. I thought I was going crazy or something.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this must be a typo, as the following shows:
$[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu] \phi = \nabla_\mu \partial_\nu \phi - \nabla_\nu \partial_\mu \phi = (\partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi - \Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu} \partial_\alpha \phi) - (\partial_\nu \partial_\mu \phi - \Gamma^\alpha_{\nu\mu} \partial_\alpha \phi) = 
- (\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu} - \Gamma^\alpha_{\nu\mu}) \partial_\alpha \phi =
- T^\alpha_{\mu\nu} \partial_\alpha \phi $

Comment: Yeah. But unfortunately, he is using this wrong equation in various parts of this paper and making some conclusions. It's really bizzare.

Comment: I guess, it is a typo, for in 2.11 he writes $T^\tau_{\cdot\alpha\beta}$ at the same place.